# What are the dual polyhedra of the face-centered cubic lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

For a given lattice $L$ we could define the set of points closest to one point more than any other.

$$  \{ x \} = \min_{\ell \in L} \|x - \ell \|  \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

This generalizes the "fractional part" in the case $L = \mathbb{Z}$ the integer lattice $\{ x\} = \min_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-n| $

For any lattice point (such as the origin) I would like to know which points are closest to $\ell$ than any other point?  In otherworse, which points have $x - \{ x\} = \ell$ ?

There are two cases $\ell = (0,0,0)$ and $ \ell = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0)$.  All the other atoms can b found by shifting the lattice a bit.

[image]

So I am asking what the [voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) cells (or [Wigner-Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell)) are for the Face-centered cubic lattice?

---

Can we simplify this expression for the Face-Centered Cubic lattice?

$$ \mathbb{Z}^3 \cup \Big((\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0) + \mathbb{Z}^3 \Big) \cup \Big((\frac{1}{2}, 0,\frac{1}{2}) + \mathbb{Z}^3 \Big) \cup \Big((0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) + \mathbb{Z}^3 \Big)$$

I suspsect it can just be written as all integer linear combinations of three appropriately chosen vectors.

Answer (score 1):

this is all in [SPLAG by Conway and Sloane](https://books.google.com/books?id=hoTjBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR33&lpg=PR33&dq=conway%20sloane%20sphere%20packing&source=bl&ots=_yiEnW93zG&sig=HPLklKlSmF4De_k5M7wvpDOBkk4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV_on4sqzKAhVBymMKHR2tBw4Q6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=conway%20sloane%20sphere%20packing&f=false). The lattice is usually doubled, so that the lattice points are integer points such that $x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod 2.$ The Voronoi cell is a [rhombic dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron)

> The rhombic dodecahedron can be used to tessellate three-dimensional
>   space. It can be stacked to fill a space much like hexagons fill a
>   plane.
>
> This polyhedron in a space-filling tessellation can be seen as the
>   Voronoi tessellation of the face-centered cubic lattice. Some minerals
>   such as garnet form

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation#Voronoi_tilings

Comment: do those things really tile 3D space??  I'd love to see a picture of that!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation#/media/File:HC_R1.png